# Объясните работу программы

Tags: c++

Решение задачи о рюкзаке.
Условия:
Одной из классических NP-полных задач является так называемая «Задача о рюкзаке». Формулируется она следующим образом. Дано n предметов, каждый из которых характеризуется весом wi и полезностью pi. Необходимо выбрать некоторый набор этих предметов так, чтобы суммарный вес этого набора не превышал W, а суммарная полезность была максимальна.

Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы написать программу, решающую задачу о рюкзаке.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
long long pol=0,col=21;
vector<int>ans(21,0);
vector<int>p(21,0);
vector<int>po(21);
vector<int>w(21);
int n,s;
void poisk(int i,int wes,long long polez,int tpcol)
{
    if(wes>s) return;
    if(polez>pol || (polez==pol && tpcol<col))
    {
        pol=polez;
        col=tpcol;
        ans=p;

    }
    if(i>n)
    {
        return;
    }
    p[i]=1;
    poisk(i+1,wes+w[i],polez+po[i],tpcol+1);
    p[i]=0;
    poisk(i+1,wes,polez,tpcol);
}

int main()
{


    cin>>n>>s;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cin>>w[i];
        cin>>po[i];
    }
    poisk(1,0,0,0);
    cout<<col<<' '<<pol<<endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(ans[i]==1)
        {
            cout<<i<<" ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Можете расписать алгоритм задачи,а то врубится не могу,что к чему.

Comment: Так этих описаний в инете как гуталина у дяди Матроскина

Comment: плохой код написан. не надо так)

Comment: Прикол в том, что код учителя XD. Написал, дал задачу,сидите разбирайтесь. Поэтому сюда и обратился)

Comment: я от ваших учителей офигеваю! Это ж что там за професор, что в с++ отсчет ведет с 1 и переменные за main выносит...

Comment: Это кстати я тоже не очень понял. Это наверное чтобы везде эти переменные можно было использовать избегая указателей.

Comment: да при чем тут указатели? Просто у вашего "учителя" знаний меньше меньше чем у меня - а я даже не программист, это просто мое хобби. А так это просто нечитаемо - я уже несколько минут пытаюсь понять что к чему.

Comment: а что записывается в s?

Comment: Максимальный вес

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Скорее всего, код переведен со старого Паскаля

Comment: Мне это не о чем не говорит) Этот код работает и прошел все тесты.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch `Это ж что там за професор, что в с++ отсчет ведет с 1 и переменные за main выносит...` — всё указывает на то, что профессор — паскалист, только недавно познакомившийся с C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведенный код тестирует все возможные наборы, вес которых не превышает заданный.
Он пробует положить i-й предмет в рюкзак или не брать его. Этим случаям соответствует два рекурсивных вызова `poisk`

Код имеет экспоненциальную сложность (2^n вариантов), реализует метод ветвей и границ, и недалеко ушёл от полного перебора. При разумных ограничениях на вес эта задача более эффективно решается динамическим программированием (описано в любой книге или статье по ДП)